# Multiple span tags

Tags: html, css

Ok so here is a tag:

```
     <ul><font face="Times New Roman" size="2">
                                 <li><span>Human Person - master</span><br> yolo,
 walker, man, <br> human, notAlien <br> youtube.com/ID</font></li>
                                 </ul>
```

And some CSS (Just the Span tag):

```
#Users span{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

For the "master" i want it in Italics font, but only the "master" and nothing else. I'm 100 percent sure this is something simple to do.

Comment: You can't do this with pure CSS. Either modify the HTML or use some JavaScript.

Comment: You have to add: span.master { font-style: italic; } and add a class "master" to the span that you want to add this style.

Comment: Also, the `font` element [is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font). You should replace it with a `span` or some other element and use CSS.

Comment: There is only one `span` element in the question text, contrary to what the title suggests. The real question seems to be “can I style a word without making it an element”; it has been asked umpteen times at SO, and the answer is still “No”. Besides, the markup in the example is invalid, and in a manner that may actually disturb styling.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela The markup is not "invalid" but alright, also I asked "multiple span tags" so I could get a solution that would let me put "master" in italics. I guess it was my fault since i did not know how to correctly word the question.

Comment: The markup is invalid (no quotes), as you can see by using http://validator.w3.org

Comment: Alright well the code is working fine on the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you alter your html (which you should -- `font` tags are deprecated), it's easy to do:

```
ul { font-family: "Times New Roman", serif; }
ul span.i { font-style: italic }


<ul>
    <li>Human Person - <span class="i">master</span>
    <br> yolo, walker, man, 
    <br> human, notAlien <br> youtube.com/ID</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the first span around an "i" tag

```
 <ul><font face="Times New Roman" size="2">
                             <li><span><i>Human Person - master</i></span><br> yolo,
   walker, man, <br> human, notAlien <br> youtube.com/ID</font></li>
                             </ul>
```

Comment: the `i` tag is deprecated for presentational use -- use css instead.

Comment: @ialarmedalien As far as I know, plans for the `i` tag to be deprecated were dropped. There is nothing listed about it on [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i).

Comment: You could always use `<em>` as a replacement, regardless.

Comment: @JoshCrozier `em` is for emphasis, not necessarily italics. However, when appropriate, `em` should be used.

Comment: From MDN: "In earlier versions of the HTML specification, the <i> tag was merely a presentational element [... ] This is no longer true, as these tags now define semantics rather than typographic appearance. The <i> tag should represent a range of text with a different semantic meaning whose typical typographic representation is italicized. "